# Hibernate using multiple joins on same table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql

I have two postgreSQL tables preference and date_etl and preference_date_etl stores their mappings.

preference_date_etl's hibernate mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com..bla.bla.PreferenceDateETL"
        table="preference_date_etl">
        <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">
            <![CDATA[preference_date_etl_id_seq]]>
                </param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        ...things....
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So now when I execute a HQL like:

```
select distinct pd.preference from PreferenceDateETL pd where pd.corporation.id=:corporationId and pd.preference.employee.deleted=false and pd.deleted=false and pd.preference.deleted=false  and  pd.dateETL.localDate>=:startDM and pd.dateETL.localDate<=:endDM and pd.preference.approvalStatus!=:approvalStatus order by pd.preference.dateCreated
```

Converting to SQL:

```
select
        distinct preference1_.id as id1_76_,
        ....things...
    from
        preference_date_etl preference0_ 
    inner join
        preference preference1_ 
            on preference0_.preference_id=preference1_.id cross 
    join
        preference preference2_ cross 
    join
        employee employee3_ cross 
    join
        date_etl dateetl5_ 
    where
        ...things... 
    order by
        preference2_.date_created
```

Problem: `preference2_.date_created` in order by clause is not in the select list hence exception `SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`.

Question: why is hibernate using two joins INNER AND CROSS on same table. If there was `preference1_.date_created` in ORDER BY list then all would be good. Ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear - this is a many to many relationship between preference and date_etl? Not a one-to-one?

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure this query to avoid using the distinct keyword, and hence order your results without a problem. To do so, make the conditions on the PreferenceDateETL object a subquery, and then retrieve all Preference objects that are in the group of preference objects linked to the PreferenceDateETL objects in your subquery. Here is the HQL:

```
from Preference p where p in 
  (select pd.preference from PreferenceDateETL pd
  where pd.corporation.id=:corporationId
  and pd.deleted=false
  and pd.dateETL.localDate>=:startDM
  and pd.dateETL.localDate<=:endDM)
and p.employee.deleted=false
and p.deleted=false
and p.approvalStatus != :approvalStatus
order by p.dateCreated
```